# Using try-catch and if-else statement to open new browser window

Tags: c#, .net, browser, if-statement, try-catch

Using: C# and .net

I want to use a try catch to display an image of the product in a new window window. Everything works unless the image does not exist meaning a (HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found) page. If that happens the button just simply does nothing when clicked.

What I want to happen is when you click the button and the file does not exist that the user is taken to a "Image does not exist" page. I have tried to do that in the following code. It does not work. Thanks for any advice!

```
        bool ImageExists = true;

        try
        {
            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch
        {
            ImageExists = false;
        }

        if (ImageExists == true)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openFoundImage", "window.open('" + PathToFolder + "');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.companysite.com/noimage.jpg");
        }
```

Edit: Changed to bool.

Comment: Well, don’t use `"Y"` and `"N"` strings, for starters. `bool imageExists = true;` `imageExists = false;` `if(imageExists) { … } else { … }`

Comment: Next up — set breakpoints on both and debug. Is the `catch` entered? Another thing to check would be in your browser; make sure that the response is an actual 404 and not just a page that says “404”.

Comment: in try check what is returned with GetResponse function when no image is there and use that response to check further and yes as minitech mentioned ... use boolean flags instead of string as flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try Catch won't trigger in this. See the link below

[How to: Request Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx)

> 4.. You can access the properties of the WebResponse or cast the WebResponse to a protocol-specific instance to read protocol-specific
>   properties. For example, to access the HTTP-specific properties of
>   HttpWebResponse, cast the WebResponse to a HttpWebResponse reference.
>   The following code example shows how to display the status information
>   sent with a response.
>
> Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

Add logic around the status return.